# PHP echo mehod ignores HTML part

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have written the following PHP code:

```
    function x_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
  
    $leistung = the_field('leistung_in_w');
    if ( ! empty( $leistung ) ) {
    echo '<div class="product-meta-leistung">Leistung:' . $leistung . 'W</div>';
    }
  
  echo '</div>';
}
```

the_field() is a function of "advanced custom fields" Plugin. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

The problem is that only the variable is output, but not the HTML part. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: cannot [replicate](https://3v4l.org/98uDG)

Comment: Have you checked the page source??...

Comment: Of course. There is nothing else the variable.

Comment: Is there any reason you echoed a second closing div?

Comment: Yes, because another function is started before, which opens the div. 

Admittedly I have changed this function a little bit, so that I get the data at exactly this point. Probably not very elegant, but it should actually work?!

Actually this has only the purpose to close the div.

Comment: A function within a function is a bit weird. In order to keep logic and presentation separated, I would highly recommend never using echo or print within a function. (In fact, echo and print should rarely be used at all, IMO)   Instead, a function should return a value that can be used for further logic or be inserted into html later. If a function in a function is needed for some reason, you could use a closure (assign the function to a variable). That way there’s no ambiguity about its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the following code worked:

```
    function x_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $leistung = get_post_meta($id,'leistung_in_w',true);
    if ( ! empty( $leistung ) ) {
    echo '<div class="product-meta-leistung">Leistung: ' . $leistung . 'W</div>';
    }
    
    
  echo '</div>';
}
```